# Copy rows to specific sheets based on value

Tags: vba, excel

Wonder if someone could point me in the right direction please as i'm getting confused with every method i try.  I've searched a lot for an answer but my scenario is a bit different to others I've found.

I have a worksheet with a number of columns and headers for each column.  Column A is "Date", column B is "Classification", column C is "Selection".  Few more columns.

What i want to do is loop through the entire sheet from A2 to the last row base on Column C.  The look at Column A for each set of rows to copy.  There could be blank rows between the dates in column A.  For each set of rows in column A (date to next date -1 row) i want to copy that range or rows to a different sheet based on Column B.

I have written the code to remove the sheets referenced by Column B and then add the sheets and add the headers.

Here is an example:  using null to signify empty cell

```
+------------+----------------+------------+
| Date       | Classification | Selection  |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| 10/08/2017 | Chris          | Selection1 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| 11/08/2017 | Chris          | Selection2 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| null       | null           | Selection3 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| null       | null           | Selection4 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| 11/08/2017 | Speed          | Selection5 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| null       | null           | Selection6 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| null       | null           | Selection7 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
```

Above there are 3 "records" that need to be copied to 2 sheets. 2 ranges to Chris and 1 range to Speed. In reality I have hundreds of "records" that need to be moved to 10+ sheets.   Basically I have to update 2 sheets for every record currently and I would like to just update a master and get Excel to do the copying work for me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Ok the Selection table is your input, could you make an example of the output? I didn't really understood it all

Comment: Could you post the code for what you've tried thus far so we can provide specific feedback?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but Im guessing there is a nicer way !!

```
Private Sub MoveThem()
Dim sws As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Set sws = Sheets("ALLSelections")
Dim selectionTop, selectionBottom As Integer
Dim sNm As String
Dim lCol As Long
Dim currentRow As Long

selectionTop = 0
selectionBottom = 0

'~~> Get the last row and last column
lRow = sws.Range("C" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = sws.Cells(1, sws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For currentRow = 2 To lRow
    If sws.Cells(currentRow, 1) > 1 Then

        If selectionTop = 0 Then
            selectionTop = currentRow

            ' Get the new sheet name
            sNm = sws.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
            If Not WksExists(sNm) Then
                ' If not already created then add to Misc
                sNm = "Misc"
            End If
            Set tws = Sheets(sNm)
        End If
    End If

    ' Check out the next row
    If Len(sws.Cells(currentRow, 1).Offset(1)) <> 0 Then
        If selectionTop <> 0 And selectionBottom = 0 Then selectionBottom = currentRow
    End If

    If currentRow = lRow Then selectionBottom = currentRow

    If selectionTop <> 0 And selectionBottom <> 0 Then
        ' We know know the range of rows
        sws.Range("A" & selectionTop, "I" & selectionBottom).Copy tws.Range("A" & tws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row)
        selectionTop = 0
        selectionBottom = 0
    Else

    End If

Next
MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub
```